# Routing error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I may be being thick but I am continually getting a page notfoundexception .

In a view I have the following:

```
<a href="{{ route('/galleryimages/{id}') }}"
```

This part is OK. In web.php I have:

```
Route::get('/galleryimages/{{id}}', function($id){
   return view('gallery_pictures.pictures',['id'=>$id]); 
});
```

The page pictures definitely exists in the subdirectory gallery_pictures.

Comment: `Route::get('/galleryimages/{id}'`

Comment: Now I feel stupid! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your route is incorrect, Laravel route parameters use one curly braces, like so: {id}. Rather than {{id}}

The helper function you are using accepts route names not route URL's, to link routes you should use the `url()` function

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

I've provided you some for reference links if you haven't already checked them out.

HTML Fix:

```
<a href="{{ url('/galleryimages/' . $id) }}">My Link</a>
```

Route Fix:

```
Route::get('/galleryimages/{id}', function($id) {
    return view('gallery_pictures.pictures', ['id'=> $id]); 
});
```

**A little extra**

If you want to use the route function you must set a name for your route, you can do it as so:

```
   Route::get('/galleryimages/{id}', function($id) {
       return view('gallery_pictures.pictures', ['id'=> $id]); 
   })->name('gallery_images');
```

Then you may access the route by doing something like so

```
<a href="{{ route('gallery_images', ['id' => $id ]) }}">My Link</a>
```